# Annotate a dataset of images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, machine-learning, detection, deep-learning

I'll be recording a new dataset using a couple of sensors: kinect, stereovision cameras.. for a project for people detection using only depth information.

But I don't know yet how can I annotate the dataset, like in [this dataset](http://www.dei.unipd.it/~munaro/KTP-dataset.html) where they provide the boundary box. 
I have only the sensors (no markers..) and I'll be recording a hundred of images..

Do you have any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools for data annotation.
Some are online and some are offline.

I can recommend 3 solutions I found good:

1. [LabelMe](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme) - Open source local version which generated JSON file per image which can be easily converted to all needed formats.
2. [RoboFlow](https://roboflow.com/) - Online solution which has a good annotation experience. Great for large scale projects.